# Java how to clear a line in the console

Tags: java, command-line, command-line-interface, user-input

So I'm just doing a random program where it creates a 2D array full of characters and prints them out. What I'm trying to do is print out the row and column of a 2D array, and have the user input what character they want to set that index in the array to. But I want the program to look clean so I don't have like 20 different lines that all look similar. For example:

```
Row: 0 Col: 0  @
```

And then I would press enter, and it would replace that line with this line

```
Row: 0 Col: 1 *
```

Right now my code looks like this:

```
public static void drawArt(String[][] art) {
    for (int row = 0; row < art.length; row++) {

        for (int col = 0; col < art[row].length; col++) {

            System.out.print("Row: " + (row + 1) + " Col: " + (col+1) + " ");
            art[row][col] = s.nextLine();
            System.out.print("\r\r");
        }   
    }   
}
```

My reasoning is that it would print the row and column, and after taking the user input it goes to a new line, so I printed two "carriage returns" one for the new line after the input, and one to replace the rows and columns.

I've seen a lot of different answers so I'll just say I am using Windows 10, and Visual Studio Code (but I have tried it from the windows cmd). So does anyone have a solution that will allow me to replace just that one line of output?

[image]

Your work was not in vain guys

Comment: "Carriage returns" does not return the carriage vertically, it returns the carriage horizontally to column 1.

Comment: yeah admittedly I only just learned what a carriage return is a few hours ago, so I'll have to find out more about them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String[][] art = new String[2][2];
for (int row = 0; row < art.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < art[row].length; col++) {
        System.out.print("Row: " + (row + 1) + " Col: " + (col+1) + " ");
        art[row][col] = s.nextLine();
        System.out.print("\033[1F\33[K");
        System.out.flush();
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(art));
```

[image]

Comment: yep this is perfect, just tested it out thank you. I think the solution below is similar but the kind of escape characters were slightly different.

Answer (score 2):

This should work on windows 10 and vs code:

```
public static void clearScreen() {  
    System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");  
    System.out.flush();  
}
```

Comment: thank you, this is the best solution I've found so far, but I only wanted it to clear just that line, but this should work for now. and thanks for the quick response

Comment: You can mark it right if this served your purpose.

Comment: The post above fits this better, but I still appreciate it